# Yup how to validate mandatory fields on null object and with same Object

Tags: typescript, validation, yup

I have a problem regarding the validation of mandatory fields which are properties of a (possibly) null object.

Here is an example schema :

```
 initialValues={{
              employee: null,
              assignedEmployee: {
                employee: null,
                selectedOption: 'assign-employee',
              },
```

If I try to validate the following object against this schema

```
const newAssignEmployeeSchema = yup.object({
    assignedEmployee: yup.object({
      selectedOption: yup.string(),
      employee: yup.string().when(['selectedOption'], {
        is: (selectedOption: RadioGroupValues, employee: Employee) =>
          selectedOption && selectedOption === 'assign-employee' && employee === null,
        then: (schema) => schema.required(t(baseTranslationKeys.form.required)),
      }),
    }),
  });
```

I have to validate both selectedOption and employee but I'm getting employee  = undefined however in real object getting "null" values - I think "employee" object attributes not recognized

I would really appreciate a bit of help on this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this schema:

```
const assignedEmployeeSchema = yup.object().shape({
    selectedOption: yup.string().required(),
    employee: yup.object().when(["selectedOption"], {
        is: (selectedOption) => selectedOption === 'assign-employee',
        then: yup.object().required()
    }).nullable()
});
```

This makes the employee object mandatory if the selectedOption is "assign-employee". Otherwise the employee object is nullable.